# Screen sharing with powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to make a screen viewer.
i have an C# server side that works good and i have C# client side that works good.
this is my C# client side code:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace WindowsFormsApp24
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private readonly TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        private NetworkStream mainStream;
        private int portNumber;

        private static Image GrabDesktop()
        {
            Rectangle bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(bound.Width, bound.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(bound.X, bound.Y, 0, 0, bound.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            return screenshot;
        }

        private void SendDesktopImage()
        {
            BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            mainStream = client.GetStream();
                binFormatter.Serialize(mainStream, GrabDesktop());
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            portNumber = 443;
            try
            {
                string ip = "192.168.1.55";
                client.Connect(ip, portNumber);

            }
            catch
            {


            }


            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                

            
            
        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendDesktopImage();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing i am trying to do, is to switch the client side from C# to powershell.
is that possible? i am searching for ideas on google for along time, I would be happy
to hear what you have to say.. many thanks.

Comment: Its possible to build a Form in powershell, so i dont see why not - BUT - its a lot more work than C#. Visual Studio manages a huge number of properties automatically when you build the form visually, doing it through code requires a lot of code for the most basic functionality eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box. Now, your question is very broad and this is not a code writing service so i suggest you break the problem apart and research each element. Start here https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+create+form Good luck!

Comment: this is really not what i asked... i dont need an powerhell gui.

Comment: Your provided code is an entire C# form and you stated you want to "...switch the client side from C# to powershell". Edit your question and be more specific.

Comment: I have a C# code that stream my screen, what i am trying to do, is Powershell code that share my screen. I am keep searching for staff around the internet to learn how to do it, and dosent found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# and Powershell are both using some version of the Dot Net runtime so the same objects and properties should be available in both, just by a different syntax. The process for converting between the two is basically this:

First you need to [load the required assemblies into powershell with `Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type). You will require several assemblies such as `System.Net`, `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms` to get access to the Objects in your code. (this is essentially the same as adding references to a C# project). Example: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing;` would load everything inside [System.Drawing.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing)

Next you need to convert the syntax from C# to powershell line by line:

Example

```
private readonly TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
```

Would become:

```
[System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient] $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
```

Mostly this process will be simplification and expanding names. Above  `[System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]` is the fully qualified type - ie the long form name of the C# Class (visible on the tooltips in Visual Studio). [`New-Object` is equivalent to `new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?)

Assuming you just want the screenshot to be taken and sent each time the script is executed you dont need to worry about writing classes or functions in powershell you can just convert each functional line of c# into powershell in a text file saved with .ps1 extension.

Comment: You dont have to use "[System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]" in powershell, and it is not what i was asked for, but thanks anyway. i will mark your answer as helpful because you still tryed to help me.